# Is std::launch::async policy needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, stdasync

What is the difference in the following:

```
std::async(my_function);
```

and

```
std::async(std::launch::async, my_function);
```

What is the difference in using the pilicy **std::launch::async** in this case??
Does the first option not launch the function asynchronously anyway??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is equivalent to passing `launch::async | launch::deferred`, in which case it is up to the implementation whether it is launched asynchronously  or merely deferred (called when a non-timed waiting function like `get()` is called on the returned future).

The idea is that by default, the implementation can choose to defer if creating a new thread isn't going to be a performance gain. To force a new thread to be created, pass `launch::async` only.

Comment: It seems to me that `launch::async` only is the preferred approach in the vast majority of use cases. And that this is likely to be a frequently-found bug in user code :(

Comment: When you say that 'this is likely to be a frequently-found bug in user code' do you mean that the omission of 'launch::async' is the bug??