# Why does async in a for loop not improve execution time?

Tags: c++, concurrency

I am trying to get a feel for concurrency, so I tried to write a more flexible version (my_comp()) of Stroustrup's example code (comp4()) from A Tour of C++ (second edition) 15.7.3, page 205. 
It gives the right answer, but it does not use concurrency to improve the execution time. My question is: why does my_comp() not act as intended, and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr auto sz = 500'000'000;
constexpr int conc_num{ 4 };

double accum(double* beg, double* end, double init)
{
    return accumulate(beg, end, init);
}

double comp4(vector<double>& v)
//From Stroustrup, A Tour of C++ (Second edition)
//15.7.3 page 205
{
    auto v0 = &v[0];
    auto sz = v.size();

    auto f0 = async(accum, v0, v0 + sz / 4, 0.0);
    auto f1 = async(accum, v0 + sz / 4, v0 + sz / 2, 0.0);
    auto f2 = async(accum, v0 + sz / 2, v0 + sz * 3 / 4, 0.0);
    auto f3 = async(accum, v0 + sz * 3 / 4, v0 + sz, 0.0);

    return f0.get() + f1.get() + f2.get() + f3.get();
}

double my_comp(vector<double>& v, int conc = 1)
//My idea of a more flexible version of comp4
{
    if (conc < 1)
        conc = 1;
    auto v0 = &v[0];
    auto sz = v.size();

    vector<future<double>> fv(conc);
    for (int i = 0; i != conc; ++i) {
        auto f = async(accum, v0 + sz * (i / conc), v0 + sz * ((i + 1) / (conc)), 0.0);
        fv[i] = move(f);
    }
    double ret{ 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i != fv.size(); ++i) {
        ret += fv[i].get();
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Calculating ..." << "\n\n";
    auto tv0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    vector<double> vc;
    vc.reserve(sz);
    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        vc.push_back(sin(i));   //Arbitrary test function
    }
    auto tv1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto durtv = duration_cast<milliseconds>(tv1 - tv0).count();
    cout << "vector of size " << vc.size() << ":  " << durtv << " msec\n\n";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    auto vc_test = vc;
    auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto s1 = accumulate(vc_test.begin(), vc_test.end(), 0.0);
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dur1 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    vc_test = vc;
    auto tt0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto s2 = my_comp(vc_test, conc_num);       //Should be faster
    auto tt1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dur2 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(tt1 - tt0).count();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    vc_test = vc;
    auto ttt0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto s3 = comp4(vc_test);       //Really is faster
    auto ttt1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dur3 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(ttt1 - ttt0).count();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    cout << dur1 << " msec\n";
    cout << "Output = " << s1 << " (accumulate)" << "\n\n";
    cout << dur2 << " msec" << "  Ratio:  " << double(dur2) / double(dur1) << "\n";
    cout << "Output = " << s2 << " (my_comp)" << "\n\n";
    cout << dur3 << " msec" << "  Ratio:  " << double(dur3) / double(dur1) << "\n";
    cout << "Output = " << s3 << " (comp4)" << "\n\n";
}
```

Compiled with Visual C++ 2019 (ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)) X64 Release. A typical output is:

424 msec
Output = 1.93496 (accumulate)

431 msec  Ratio:  1.01651
Output = 1.93496 (my_comp)

117 msec  Ratio:  0.275943
Output = 1.93496 (comp4)

I am aware of parallel algorithms and std::reduce. My question is not how to optimize this particular calculation, but rather to learn something about how to write concurrent code that acts as intended.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659215/is-stdlaunchasync-policy-needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here: `(i / conc)`. Once `0 <= i < conc`, and `i` and `conc` are integer, this means that this calculation is always zero.

To solve your problem, remove the parentheses:

```
auto f = async(accum, v0 + sz * i / conc, v0 + sz * (i + 1) / conc, 0.0);
```

Comment: Right you are. Thank you.